# Idle handler function is not running at the exact specified interval

Tags: applescript

The script uses idle handler that runs every 5 minutes and alerts me to perform the task.                                                                                           But the script always runs late by 10-40 seconds. I am not sure why that is happening.

```
global numberOfBeeps, beepcycle

on idle
    
    if beepcycle is greater than 0 then
        say "Update 5 minute data and watchlist " using "Serena"
        set beepcycle to beepcycle - 1
    else
        say "Update 30 minute data and watchlist" using "Kate"
        set beepcycle to 5
        
    end if
    return 300
    
end idle

on run
    set beepcycle to 6
end run
```

Comment: The idle handler isn’t real-time, it fires when the run loop checks the timer.  Things like repeat loops and saying stuff can delay the timer check if it is happening at the same time, so it would depend on what else the script is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The **if statement** in your script adds this 10-40 seconds to the **on idle** handler. So, you should correct the **return time** of **on idle** handler some way. For example, you can do something like this:

```
global numberOfBeeps, beepcycle

on idle
    
    set currentDate to (get current date)
    if beepcycle is greater than 0 then
        say "Update 5 minute data and watchlist " using "Serena"
        set beepcycle to beepcycle - 1
    else
        say "Update 30 minute data and watchlist" using "Kate"
        set beepcycle to 5
    end if
    set timeElapsed to (get current date) - currentDate
    
    return (300 - timeElapsed)
end idle

on run
    set beepcycle to 6
end run
```

Comment: Still the same. Output gets delayed and continues getting delayed as the script progresses.